# Is there any standard or heuristic for deciding on the dimensions and filters of a convolution layer for image processing?

Tags: image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, image-recognition, image-segmentation

I reposted this from StackOverflow since it does not meet StackOverflow's guideline to focus on programming and coding questions. [Link to the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78086716/is-there-any-standard-or-heuristic-for-deciding-on-the-dimensions-and-filters-of)

I want to find ways other than trial and error to select the number of filters and the kernel size of my convolutional layers. The best I could come up with is to start with a kernel size of three and keep doubling it to see the effect on the network performance: 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. I could try to keep selecting odd-numbered filters as suggested here: [Deciding optimal kernel size for CNN.](https://towardsdatascience.com/deciding-optimal-filter-size-for-cnns-d6f7b56f9363) As for the number of layers and filters, I start with 64 filters as my default and, as usual, keep increasing or decreasing based on the network performance. After that, I do trial and error on the number of layers. The order in which I tune a parameter (kernel size first, layer count first, or filter count first) might skew my tests and prevent me from picking other combinations. If I try to experiment with more combinations, I would take too much time to train all the models. I don't want to modify two or more parameters at once since I can't tell which one causes an improvement or decrease in model performance. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes there are some kind of "standard" that most papers tend to re-use for kernel dimension, but almost entirely for empirical reasons. Usually you prefer having powers of 2, also. For kernel size, you can stack several layers of 3x3 filters to obtain the same receptive field as 5x5 or 7x7 filters.